# Compare Plots in matlab

Tags: image-processing, graph, matlab

I have two plots in matlab where in I have plotted x and y coordinates. If I have these two plots, is it possible to compare if the plots match? Can I obtain numbers to tell how well they match?

Note that the graphs could possibly be right/left/up/down shifted in plot (turning axis off is not problem), scaled/rotated (I would also like to know if it is skewed, but for now, it is not a must).

It will not need to test color elements, color inversion and any other complicated graphic properties than basic ones mentioned above.

If matlab is not enough, I would welcome other tools.

Note that I cannot simply take the absolute difference of x- and y- values. I could obtain x-absolute difference average and y-absolute difference and then average but I need a combined error. I need to compare the graph.

Graphs to be compared.

[image]

**EDIT**

Direct Correlation does not work for me.

For a different set of data: I got .94 correlation. This is very high for given data. noticing that one data is fluctuating less and faster than other.

[image]

Comment: Can you post example graphs?

Comment: It will take a while. But I will try to post one.

Comment: And expected output, what do you think the output should be for the example graphs?

Comment: @HughNolan I want numbers indicating how much they match something like 50% match...

Comment: Yes but what does that mean? What are your matching criteria?

Comment: It might be simpler to do correlation on the data itself rather than plotting first?

Comment: @HughNolan, ah, I want to compare the contours, precisely, the shapes of the graph, rise, fall, how steep the rise is. Like, for above plots, I would expect around ~40% for above graphs. Not sure if I put it clearly. Also note that y might not necessarily be function of x. meaning that I might have two y values corresponding to same x value. I did not have such graph above, but that may arise.

Comment: As @RogerRowland says, what you are doing sounds like calculating a correlation coefficient - using the Matlab function `corrcoef` on the two y vectors will give you an appropriate output between -1 and 1. 0 means there is no relationship at all, 1 means that there is an exact correspondance, -1 means there is an exact opposite correspondance. If your vectors are different lengths, you may want to look into the `xcorr` function.

Comment: I did not mean the overall rise and fall but rise and fall at let's say every point. The general correlation accounts for linear relation only. Does corrcoef of matlab even takes into account complex relations? Also, as I told, my plots is not necessarily a function of x. Does it work in that case too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the plotted data with this code

```
x = 10:100;  
y = log10(x);  
plot(x,y);  

h = gcf;  
axesObjs = get(h, 'Children'); %axes handles  
dataObjs = get(axesObjs, 'Children'); %handles to low-level graphics objects in axes  
objTypes = get(dataObjs, 'Type'); %type of low-level graphics object  
xdata = get(dataObjs, 'XData'); %data from low-level grahics objects  
ydata = get(dataObjs, 'YData');
```

Then you can do a correlation between xdata and ydata for example, or any kind of comparison. The coefficient R will indicate a percent match.

```
[R,P] = corrcoef(xdata, ydata);
```

You would also be interested in comparing the axes limits in the graphical current axes. For example

```
R = ( diff(get(h_ax1,'XLim')) / diff(get(h_ax2,'XLim')) ) + ...
( diff(get(h_ax1,'YLim')) / diff(get(h_ax2,'YLim')) )
```

where h_ax1 is the handle of the first axe and h_ax2 for the second one. Here, you will have a comparison between values of (XLim + YLim). The possible comparisons with different gca properties are really vast though.

**EDIT**

To compare two sets of points, you may use other metrics than analytical relationship. I think  of distances or convergences such as the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). A script is available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26738-hausdorff-distance) in matlab central. I used such distance to compare letter shapes. In the wikipedia page, the 'Applications' section is of importance (edge detector for thick shapes, but it may not be pertinent to your particular problem).

Comment: I have edited my answer to include overall shape distances that may be more suitable to your problem.

Comment: This sounds better. Thanks.